# Google Sheet API batchUpdateByDataFilter PHP Function

Tags: google-sheets-api

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdateByDataFilter

We have used above function in our code, while we are passing the more than 50 or 100 records within the array records then given 400 bad request array in response.

Can anyone describe the limit of the total values that we are going to pass within the above function?

Here is my code:

```
$batchupdate = array("valueInputOption" => "RAW", "data" => $dataarray);
try {
    $requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesByDataFilterRequest($batchupdate);
    $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->BatchUpdateByDataFilter($spreadsheetId, $requestBody);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Please attach a sanitized version of your request body so we can see if the problem is not with that.

Answer (score 0):

## Troubleshooting:

### Problems with the Request

Until you attach a sanitized version of your Request body we cannot be sure about the root-cause of the problem you are facing.

However, an error 400 means that the request you did is invalid. So, most likely, the problem is in that.

Check if your request object is formatted as detailed on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdateByDataFilter#request-body).

### Problems with the Client

If you are able to use the Try this API sidebar with the same Request Body then it could be related to the PHP client.

> Note: This is language independent. Create a JSON Object that has the same structure as your request body.

If that's the case, we will need to see more of your code to verify that you are not using your valid Request body in an invalid way (eg. sending it encapsulated in another object).

By referencing the [PHP Library documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesByDataFilterRequest.html) you can see the properties of the objects you can use.

Comment: Yes, Sure, Please have a look with below request body.

$batchupdate = array( "valueInputOption" => "RAW", "data" => $dataarray );
try{
 $requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesByDataFilterRequest($batchupdate);

 $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->BatchUpdateByDataFilter( $spreadsheetId, $requestBody );

}
catch(Exception $e) {
     echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}

I didn't found the PHP API test in right sidebar.

Comment: @SagarPatel I've updated your question to add this code, but it would be helpful as well to have your error message. Also, are you authenticating with an API key, OAuth or none?

Comment: Error Code: 400 bad request array in response.

Comment: @SagarPatel this means the request you sent with the API is malformed.

Could you add to your question the result of `echo $batchupdate`?